# User profile synchronization service is not working in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am experiencing issues with user profile synchronisation in SharePoint 2010.

**Problem:** Sharepoint is neither writing back to active directory nor updating user profiles from the active directory.

- Incremental/full sync is starting and finishing but not updating user profile information
- User profile service and user profile sync service is showing "started"
- Nothing is in ULS log
- I doubled checked mapping some are user fields are set to export and some fields are set for import
- I assigned farm account these permissions on domain root level :
- replicated changes directory
- Create all child object
- create all properties

There is one error I am getting in Windows event log but not sure if it is the reason behind sync problem. I am getting this error every time when UPSS runs or every user screenshot of the error is:
[image]

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Detailed log:

```
    The server encountered an unexpected error in the synchronization engine:

 "BAIL: MMS(5956): eafam.cpp(1298): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): eafam.cpp(946): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): eafam.cpp(1013): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): amexec.cpp(1701): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): amexec.cpp(2086): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): eaf.cpp(1417): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): eaf.cpp(657): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
ERR: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(5270): 0x80230304 - export-flow failed 0x80230304
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(5271): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(4862): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(10882): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(10566): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(2546): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(4374): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(8713): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(3842): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
ERR: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(3858): 0x80230304 - CS to MV to CS synchronization failed 0x80230304: [CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WR2\,DC\=WWMI   JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU]
BAIL: MMS(5956): synccoreimp.cpp(3649): 0x80230304 (The image or dimage already has an attribute with that name.)
ERR: MMS(5956): syncmonitor.cpp(2515): SE: Rollback SQL transaction for: 0x80230304
MMS(5956): SE: CS image begin
MMS(5956): <cs-object cs-dn="CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\= WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU" id="{85319C60-E890-E811-BF10-005056830AE3}" object-type="user">
 <unapplied-export>
  <delta operation="none" dn="CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\=WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU">
   <anchor encoding="base64">mgAAAEMATgA9AFAAaAB1AG8AbgBnACAATgBnAHUAeQBlAG4AXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
  </delta>
 </unapplied-export>
 <escrowed-export>
  <delta operation="none" dn="CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\=WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU">
   <anchor encoding="base64">mgAAAEMATgA9AFAAaAB1AG8AbgBnACAATgBnAHUAeQBlAG4AXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
  </delta>
 </escrowed-export>
 <unconfirmed-export>
  <delta operation="none" dn="CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\=WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU">
   <anchor encoding="base64">mgAAAEMATgA9AFAAaAB1AG8AbgBnACAATgBnAHUAeQBlAG4AXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
  </delta>
 </unconfirmed-export>
 <pending-import>
  <delta operation="update" dn="CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\=WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU">
   <anchor encoding="base64">mgAAAEMATgA9AFAAaAB1AG8AbgBnACAATgBnAHUAeQBlAG4AXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
   <attr name="PositionFinal" operation="delete" type="string" multivalued="false">
   </attr>
   <attr name="SPS-JobTitle" operation="delete" type="string" multivalued="false">
   </attr>
  </delta>
 </pending-import>
 <synchronized-hologram>
  <entry dn="CN=John Elis\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\=WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU">
   <anchor encoding="base64">mgAAAEMATgA9AFAAaAB1AG8AbgBnACAATgBnAHUAeQBlAG4AXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
   <primary-objectclass>user</primary-objectclass>
   <objectclass>
    <oc-value>user</oc-value>
   </objectclass>
   <dn-attr name="Manager" multivalued="false">
    <dn-value>
     <dn>CN=Ben Marais\,OU\=CIDM\,OU\=WWMI  JOHN2\,DC\=WWMI  JOHN\,DC\=US\,DC\=EDU\,DC\=AU</dn>
     <anchor encoding="base64">lAAAAEMATgA9AEIAZQBuACAATQBhAHIAYQBpAHMAXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
    </dn-value>
   </dn-attr>
   <attr name="AccountName" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>WWMI  JOHN\John.Elis</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="Department" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Infect. Dis. &amp; WMI cro.</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="FirstName" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>John</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="LastName" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Elis</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="PersonalTitle" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>MS</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="PositionFinal" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Student - PhD</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="PreferredName" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>John Elis</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="RoomNumberNew" type="string" multivalued="true">
    <value>Desk 31A</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="SID" type="binary" multivalued="false">
    <value encoding="base64">AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAXntaoafQvBtxQKYrKxcAAA==</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="SPS-ClaimProviderID" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Windows</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="SPS-ClaimProviderType" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Windows</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="SPS-DistinguishedName" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>CN=John Elis,OU=CIDM,OU=WWMI  JOHN2,DC=WWMI  JOHN,DC=US,DC=EDU,DC=AU</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="SPS-JobTitle" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Student - PhD</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="StaffNumber" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>10940</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="Title" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>Student - PhD</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="UserName" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>John.Elis</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="UserProfile_GUID" type="binary" multivalued="false">
    <value encoding="base64">ZWY1M2E1YjAtM2ZjZC00Nzk5LWIwNTEtNmNmY2Y1NTE1NWZh</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="WorkPhone" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>N/A</value>
   </attr>
   <attr name="domain" type="string" multivalued="false">
    <value>WWMI  JOHN</value>
   </attr>
  </entry>
 </synchronized-hologram>
 <anchor encoding="base64">mgAAAEMATgA9AFAAaAB1AG8AbgBnACAATgBnAHUAeQBlAG4AXAAsAE8AVQBcAD0AQwBJAEQATQBcACwATwBVAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAMgBcACwARABDAFwAPQBXAE0ASQBNAFIAXAAsAEQAQwBcAD0AVQBTAFkARABcACwARABDAFwAPQBFAEQAVQBcACwARABDAFwAPQBBAFUAAAA=</anchor>
 <connector>1</connector>
 <connector-state>normal</connector-state>
 <seen-by-import>1</seen-by-import>
 <rebuild-in-progress>0</rebuild-in-progress>
 <obsoletion>0</obsoletion>
 <need-full-sync>0</need-full-sync>
 <placeholder-parent>0</placeholder-parent>
 <placeholder-link>0</placeholder-link>
 <placeholder-delete>0</placeholder-delete>
 <pending>1</pending>
 <ref-retry>0</ref-retry>
 <rename-retry>0</rename-retry>
 <sequencers>
  <current>
   <batch-number>1560</batch-number>
   <sequence-number>275545</sequence-number>
  </current>
  <unapplied>
   <batch-number>1560</batch-number>
   <sequence-number>275545</sequence-number>
  </unapplied>
  <original>
   <batch-number>1560</batch-number>
   <sequence-number>275545</sequence-number>
  </original>
 </sequencers>
 <import-delta-operation>modify</import-delta-operation>
 <export-delta-operation>none</export-delta-operation>
 <pending-ref-delete>0</pending-ref-delete>
 <ma-id>{E8AA0CD0-097B-49A0-BEA2-40F89763B7BB}</ma-id>
 <ma-name>MOSS-5f25328d-eb0f-4406-a90d-b83cbb5667d9</ma-name>
 <partition-id>{59EFCA0D-71B9-4624-AE13-8B2A2D3AB88A}</partition-id>
 <import-errordetail first-occurred="2018-08-25 19:05:24.623" date-occurred="2018-09-11 07:31:47.293" retry-count="108" error-type="unexpected-error">
  <import-status>
 <algorithm-step ma-id="{F0B1ECC6-8C34-4E18-B06D-BFFA564CF8F6}" dn="CN=John Elis,OU=CIDM,OU=WWMI  JOHN2,DC=WWMI  JOHN,DC=US,DC=EDU,DC=AU">export-flow</algorithm-step>
<rules-error-info>
 <context>
  <attribute-mapping dest-attr="roomNumber" context-id="{F9622AE2-C914-45AF-9513-91DC0D0AA81D}">
 <direct-mapping>
  <src-attribute>SPS_MV_String_RoomNumberNew</src-attribute>
 </direct-mapping>
</attribute-mapping>

 </context>
</rules-error-info>


</import-status>

 </import-errordetail>
 <mv-link lineage-id="{F434C74C-B9B8-4BCD-858B-B221447E1FC7}" lineage-type="provisioning-rules" lineage-time="2018-07-26 15:27:19.867">{84319C60-E890-E811-BF10-005056830AE3}</mv-link>
 <last-import-delta-time>2018-09-11 07:30:02.617</last-import-delta-time>
 <last-export-delta-time>2018-08-23 19:54:58.673</last-export-delta-time>
</cs-object>

MMS(5956): SE: CS image end
Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.49"
```

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, remove all mapping in the 'Title' property, please follow the steps below:

1. Go to central administration->manage service application->user profile service application.
2. manage user properties->find and edit “Title” property.
3. Remove all mapping in the “Property Mapping for Syncronization” section.
4. Click on OK to save changes.
5. Then start a full import in user profile service application.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Event ID 6301 is logged in the Application log when you run the User Profile Synchronization service with a BDC connection on a SharePoint 2010 Server.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2435284/event-id-6301-is-logged-in-the-application-log-when-you-run-the-user-p)

[User Profile Import from BDC fails on SharePoint Server 2010 with Event ID 6301.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steve_chen/user-profile-import-from-bdc-fails-on-sharepoint-server-2010-with-event-id-6301/)

[Resolving ‘Duplicate mapping’ error (Event 6301) for ‘Title’ property in SharePoint user Profile Service Application property Mapping.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bkr_sharepoint/2014/06/08/resolving-duplicate-mapping-error-event-6301-for-title-property-in-sharepoint-user-profile-service-application-property-mapping/)